# Replace all characters until backslash n times

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string, a file path, something like

`$string = "customer-service/tweep/cs/gsergsergrs/2017-20190Course-Schedule.pdf"`

I want to replace all the characters before the backslash with 3 dashes, so that it returns:

`$string = ---/---/---/---/2017-20190Course-Schedule.pdf`

I have tried using this preg_replace pattern, but it returns `---/2017-20190Course-Schedule.pdf`

`preg_replace( "/(.+\/)+/", "---/", $string);`

Any way to run the replace on every instance of the pattern matching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~[^/]+/~', "---/", $string);
// => ---/---/---/---/2017-20190Course-Schedule.pdf
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/xIzcgT).

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/wQG4KR/1). Details:

- `[^/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a forward slash.

Note that `/` does not have to be escaped since `~` delimiters are used. The `preg_replace` function replaces *all* non-overlapping occurrences with the replacement pattern, `---/`, so no need using a repeated capturing group (as in the original attempt).

Comment: @Ice76 `~` is a [regex delimiter](http://php.net/manual/pl/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). It is not a part of the pattern itself. Read about how patterns are using in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/pl/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). Then, I can suggest [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com).

Comment: Will check all those out. Thanks!